# Non Noetherian ring with only one prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Give an example of non Noetherian ring with only one prime ideal.

In one of the topics I have read that $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]/(x_ix_j)$ will be an example. I know that the ring $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]$ is NOT Noetherian ring. But can anyone show in detail why the above example will work?

I am studying commutative algebra for a short time. So the detailed explanation would be very useful.

I would be very grateful for your help!

And please do not duplicate this question since others topics has only answer no explanation.

**EDIT:** I will provide detailed explanation of rschwieb's answer in order to clarify things for myself.

Let $\mathbb{k}$ is field and consider the ring $\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\dots] $ and ideal generated by all products $x_ix_j$ for $1\leq i\leq j<\infty$ and call this ideal $J$. Consider the following quotient-ring $R:=\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\dots]/J$. Consider and ideal $I$ in $R$, where $I=(x_1+J,x_2+J,\dots)$. Note that you've written $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ but I guess that it's incorrect since element in $R$ has form $f+J$, right?

Also note that an ideal $I$ is nilpotent because $I^2$ is zero $R$, i.e. $I^2=J$. Ideal $I$ is maximal in $R$ because the quotient-ring $R/I$ is field because any nonzero element in $R/I$ has form $(c+J)+I$, where $c\in \mathbb{k}$ and $c\neq 0$. But it definitely has inverse since $\mathbb{k}$ is field.

Thus, an ideal $I$ in $R$ is nilpotent and maximal. Hence $R$ has unique prime ideal which is $I$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: *Note that you've written $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ but I guess that it's incorrect* . No, I wrote "$(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ in the quotient" meaning  $(x_1,x_2,\dots)/I$, which is the same thing as what you said, modulo the chosen notation.  One should probably include the comment Badam Baplan made to make the final conclusion clear.

Comment: Why don't post the edit as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the $i,j$ in the denominator range over all indices.

In that case, the ideal $(x_1,x_2\ldots)$ in the quotient $k[x_1,x_2\ldots]/I$ where $I$ is generated by the pairwise products of indeterminates is both maximal and nilpotent, so it is the unique prime ideal.

Comment: Could you give more details, please? I really cannot understand what ideal is prime here? And in what ring do we consider our ideal? I would be very grateful for detailed and good answer.

Comment: @ZFR I wrote more explicitly about the ideal and ring. You should be able to confirm now.

Comment: How to prove that if $R$ commutative ring and an ideal $I$ is nilpotent and maximal then there is only one prime ideal in $R$, namely $I$?

Comment: I guess that you are using this fact here, right?

Comment: @ZFR That would work, yes

Comment: @ZFR If $I$ is nilpotent and maximal then we have $I^n = 0$ for some $n$.  If $P$ is any prime of $R$ then we thus have $I^n \subseteq P$.  Since $P$ is prime we have $I \subseteq P$, hence $I = P$ by maximality of $I$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan yes! For commutative rings a similar argument works for a maximal nil ideal.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, your reasoning shows that any prime ideal $P$ in $R$ is equal to $I$. But I guess that it does not show that there is unique prime ideal because if we have two different maximal nilpotent ideal $I_1$ and $I_2$ and we can apply such reasoning to both of them and we get two distinct prime ideals. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ZFR If all prime ideals are equal to a single ideal, there is only one unique prime ideal.  The scenario you describe is an absurdity given that.

Comment: Dear rschwieb, i added an edit to my question where I wrote down the detailed version of your answer. Could you check it please? I would like to know do I understand it correctly.

Comment: The scenario which I've described is absurd? Why? If $I_1, I_2$ are maximal, nilpotent ideals in $R$ such that $I_1\neq I_2$. Suppose that $P$ is any prime ideal in $R$ then by above reasoning i can show that $P=I_1$ and $P=I_2$ which implies that $I_1=I_2$ which is contradiction. Right?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, it *is*. That's why believing there could possibly be two distinct maximal nilpotent ideals is an absurdity. Because it leads to a contradiction.  Therefore when you offer the possibility as evidence that "I guess that it does not show that there is unique prime ideal..." it is not a valid concern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for remark! What about my reasoning in edit? is everything ok there?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, from what I can tell I think you got it.

Comment: Dear rschwieb! I am very happy that you've helped me and also you helped me for many times! Thank you very much for patience and checking!

Comment: @ZFR no problem.